# Customise pagination for resource in adminjs/ admin bro

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, admin-bro

I am new to admin bro/ adminjs, I am looking to modify pagination for a resource. I did see the example here

https://adminjs.co/Pagination.html

and tried, but I am missing how to configure it with resource. Can anyone point me to full example or how to configure the pagination for a resource.

Comment: This worked https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/adminjs/issues/936

Answer (score 2):

In [source](https://docs.adminjs.co/adminjs_src_backend_actions_list_list-action.ts.html) code `perPage` parameter get from `query`. So, you must set for every request.

```html
actions: {
    list: {
        before: async (request, context) => {
            request.query.perPage = 1;
            return request
        }
    }
}
```